# PostgreSQL One ID multiple values

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres table where one id may have multiple Channel values as follows

```
ID   |Channel | Column 3 | Column 4
_____|________|__________|_________
1    | Sports | x        | null
1    | Organic| x        | z
2    | Organic| null     | q
3    | Arts   | b        | w
3    | Organic| e        | r
4    | Sports | sp       | t
```

No ID will have a duplicate channel name, and no ID will be both Sports and Arts. That is, ID 1 could have a Sports and Organic channel, a Sports and Arts channel, but not two sports or two organic entries and not a Sports and Arts channel. I want all IDs to be in the query, but if there is a non-organic channel I prefer that. The result I would want would be

```
ID   |Channel | Column 3 | Column 4
_____|________|__________|_________
1    | Sports | x        | null
2    | Organic| null     | q
3    | Arts   | b        | w
4    | Sports | sp       | t
```

I feel like there is some CTE here, a rank and partition or something that could do the trick, but I'm just not getting it. I'm only including Columns 3 and 4 to show there are extra columns.

Does anyone have any ideas on the code to deploy here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DISTINCT ON` with an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
       id, channel, column3, column4
FROM atable
ORDER BY id, channel = 'Organic';
```

This relies on the fact that `FALSE < TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. This worked for the information i gave to you. There was a bit more info I didn't include in the original question. Your answer was correct, but I needed a slightly different solution to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a rank over function
ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by salesforce_id order by case when channel is organic then 0 else 1 end desc, timestamp desc) as id_rank

I didn't include in the original question that I had a timestamp! This works now. Thanks